# adding views dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am using the following layout and want to add textviews one below another dynamically(depending on the data I want to display)

```
main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

So I tried this

```
public class Feeds extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
      String s= b.getString("datapack");

      Log.w("String",s);
      String data[]=s.split("#");




String temp="";
      LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contain);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
      relative.setLayoutParams(lp);


      for(int i=1;i<data.length;i++)
      {Log.w("i data",data[i]);
          temp=temp  + data[i] + ",";
          Log.w("tag",temp);
          if(i%5==0)
          {Log.w("data",temp);
              TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
              tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
              tv.setId(i);
              tv.setText(temp);
              relative.addView(tv, lp);
              temp=null;

          }

      }
      l.addView(relative);




    }
}
```

I am using Scrollview for the first time so that is crating a bit of problem but the main problem is that the textviews in the relative layout overlap one another.How can I specify the gap between each view??

[image: Overlapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are defining the positions for each textview, ie layout_below, layout_toLeftOf... If no positions are defined the relative layout stacks each view in the upper left corner.

**Addition**

It seems digulino and I agree. I would like to add that you should be able to get the layout scheme you want with only a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView, maybe a HorizontalScrollView too if you want horizontal scrolling with fling gesture support.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to know.Where do I add these fields??

Comment: Use the addRule function of [layoutParams.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding views into a RelativeLayout you have to set where the view will be placed, different than LinearLayout that you only need to add the views inside there.

Trye to change to this

```
LinearLayout layout= new LinearLayout (getApplicationContext());
  layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And here you go a little tip. Do not do this

```
if(i%5==0)
{Log.w("data",temp);
```

try to do this

```
if(i%5==0){
   Log.w("data",temp);
```

it's better to read and understand

Comment: it is also a good practice to set layout_gravity for a LinearLayout so that the views do not overlap...