# Adding dynamic views in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have the same problem as that of this [adding views dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261993/adding-views-dynamically)

I'm creating an application to tag photos in image using android.

So once i tap at a position, i need to create a EditText where i can type.

I was able to do this, but the problem is when i edit the edittext, it is not invalidating the already existing data. It overlaps with the previous data that was present.

Here is how i inflate and add the

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

//.....

frmLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
frmLayout.setFocusable(true);

mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());

View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_layout,null);
view.setX(event.getX());
view.setY(event.getY());
frmLayout.addView(view,250,250);

//....
}
```

tag_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edittext1"
        android:text="D"
        />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

TIA

Comment: Just as a note here.. AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. You should be using some other layouts.. provided that is not causing the issue here anyway.

Comment: @AndroSelva I want to exactly create a new view in the position he taps. So i went with Absolute. Is there any other layout when i can create at a specific (x,y)

Comment: probably a frame layout..

Answer (score 0):

1. Call a method on tap on Image.
2. Inside that method,get the position of touch.
   3.Create new EditText
   EditText et= new EditText(context);
   MainLayout.addView(et);
3. and set the position of that EditText as position of Touch

You can ask if you have any further queries!